# Can someone help me find the bottleneck in this code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, optimization

I have the following chunk of code inside a loop that runs about 5000 times.

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<int?, StatusLog>> allLogs = db.StatusLogs
    .Where(sl => sl.ID.Value.Equals(foo))
    .GroupBy(sl=>sl.bar);

List<StatusLog> statusLogs = new List<StatusLog>();

foreach (var group in allLogs)
{
    // do stuff that adds to statusLogs
}

if (statusLogs.Count > 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Im trying to find a bottleneck in the code that takes about 50ms for seemingly no reason.

Even when `allLogs` is empty and has no groups, it takes 50ms to step from

```
foreach (var group in allLogs)
```

to

```
if (statusLogs.Count > 0)
```

stepping through the evaluation of `var group` and `in allLogs` only takes about 3ms, so how does the jump to the next statement take 50ms when the code inside the `foreach` loop doesn't even run?

Comment: You have to provide more code.

Comment: 50ms is a fairly short amount of time compared to the system clock resolution. How are you measuring this time? Are you certain that other processes aren't using a lot of CPU while measuring this?

Comment: You think the round trip to the database is free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `allLogs` is *lazy* in nature -- it will actually hit the database when first enumerated through in the `foreach` (see "Deferred query execution" [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx)).  If you materialize the collection before hand like the following, you will see that it steps through the `foreach` quickly:

```
db.StatusLogs
    .Where(sl => sl.ID.Value.Equals(foo))
    .GroupBy(sl=>sl.bar)
    .ToList();  // <-- pull the query results into memory
```

Comment: For the record this didn't solve the problem, it only moved where the 50ms happened. I just accepted an answer so that hopefully the barrage of downvotes would end.

Comment: @iMassakre there is no _problem_ to solve here.  Making a database call will take time, no matter where you do it.  I only tried to explain why stepping through foreach takes time in your case.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Well I guess there is no way to fix this then. It just seems insane that it will take like 13 minutes to generate a report of 5000 items.

Answer (score 2):

spilt it into db access and then the for loop and time each one (with StopWatch class)

```
var allLogs = db.StatusLogs
    .Where(sl => sl.ID.Value.Equals(foo))
    .GroupBy(sl=>sl.bar).ToList();// tolist forces query to run now

foreach (var group in allLogs)
{
    // do stuff that adds to statusLogs
}
```